# How to properly run googletest with global static initializer methods

Tags: googletest

I wonder if anyone have practical experience of how to handle static initializer functions in googletest?

For example assume you have an external library which requires you to run ExtLib::Init() exactly once, and no more, for each process. The code you need to test then obviously have to use this ExtLib.

Then assume you have a couple of tests running with some EXPECT_DEATH. As I understand it some of these death tests run in a subprocess.
Do I have to call ExtLib::Init within the body that is passed to EXPECT_DEATH or how do I cope with it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `AddGlobalTestEnvironment()` to register a class to perform [global setup and tear-down](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down), such as initializing external libraries.

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#how-it-works), when using the "threadsafe" style of death tests, every death test spawns a new process that executes the test program but only runs the one test. I assume it will also run global setup and tear-down, but you will have to check this. For example, by writing a message to `std::cerr` or using a debugger.

This style is always used on Windows.

When using the "fast" style, it probably depends on the external library whether it needs to be initialized again or it's state is preserved over a `fork()`/`clone()` call.